# Version Suffix not honored when creating NuGet packages with project references

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core, csproj

I recently migrated my .NET Core projects from `project.json` to `.csproj`. The solution contains multiple projects, some of which references project using `ProjectReference`.

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\RawRabbit\RawRabbit.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

I have a PowerShell script that I've for a long time, that traverses the project folders and creates NuGet packages for each project

```
dotnet pack -c Release -o ..\..\artifacts --version-suffix=$buildSuffix
```

Where `$buildSuffix` is something like `beta7`. The version suffix is shared between all project dependencies, meaning that all project dependencies are for a pre-release uses the same version suffixed (`beta7` in this example).

In order for the package to get the right version suffix, I've updated the csproj so that my projects are using `VersionPrefix` rather than `Version`

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <VersionPrefix>2.0.0</VersionPrefix>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

The NuGet package gets the right version number (e.g. `2.0.0-beta7`), but the  project dependencies in the `nuspec` file (within the `nupkg` file) are referenced without the `VersionSuffix` used during build.

```
<dependencies>
  <group targetFramework=".NETStandard1.5">
    <dependency id="RawRabbit" version="2.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
  </group>
</dependencies>
```

This is problematic, as my newly created pre-release gets a dependency an release that does not exist (in this case `2.0.0` rather than `2.0.0-beta7`).

I'm not really sure if this is the expected behavior, if so: any ideas as how I would configure my build so that it honors the `VersionSuffix` when creating NuGet package?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so looks like it is a bug after all:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4337
https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6025